# Is mysqli bind_param the culprit? Cannot save special characters like €

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to create some pages using PHP / MySQL.

My database table is set to `utf8_general_ci` and so are the table columns. If I use phpmyadmin and manually insert a page I can type all the € I want and they will be inserted as €. I can display this perfectly too.

However when I am trying to insert a page using mysqli the € will be converted to â‚¬

I am not doing any conversions of any kind. If I echo the page column fiels just before I am about to insert the page it still displays the € correctly.

The code:

```
$connection = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'some_db');

$query  = 'INSERT INTO page (ID, title, content) VALUES (?, ?, ?)';
$params = array('iss', 'NULL', 'test title', '€ some content');

$stmt = $connection->prepare($query);

call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), by_ref($params));

$stmt->execute();
```

The `by_ref` function only makes a reference, nothing else. All works fine except it gives me a headache when it doesn't insert € correctly. Maybe it is not the bind_param, but something else. I would however like to know the answer!

**Update:**

Thanks to Digital Precision I figured out I would have to make sure the connection was going to use 'utf8'. However I only need to set it when using INSERT or UPDATE as SELECT did give me results back in utf8. Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHPMyAdmin may be explicitly setting the connection charset to UTF-8 which is why it may work through the admin interface and not through your script. Check out [mysqli::set_charset](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php) for more detailed info.

```
$connection->set_charset('utf8');
```

Edit

Try taking out the call_user_function:

```
$connection = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'some_db');

$query  = 'INSERT INTO page (ID, title, content) VALUES (?, ?, ?)';
//$params = array('iss', 'NULL', 'test title', '€ some content');

$stmt = $connection->prepare($query);

// Replace this
//call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), by_ref($params));

// With this
$stmt->bind_param('iss', 'NULL', 'test title', '€ some content'); 

$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Doesn't help me when I insert, but makes selecting the page extra weird (i.e the â‚¬ is converted again to Ã¢â€šÂ¬)

Comment: @Tessmore: Try `$connection->get_charset()` and see what the current value is.

Comment: @Tessmore: A couple of other things to try; try the query without using bind, and try binding outside of the call_user_func_array.

Comment: There is no `get_charset();` but if you ment `character_set_name();` it returns latin1 without setting a charset, but I followed your advise and did `set_charset('utf8');`, well it gives me utf8 encoding, but still the € is being converted. I will try using the query without bind now, but I don't know what you mean with setting bind outside call_user_func_array.

Comment: Without the bind_param it works... but I need to use bind_params to avoid SQL injections

Comment: According to php.net there is a get_charset(), http://us2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.get-charset.php

Comment: Ahh I didn't read the error correct. But yes even if it shows utf8 in the var_dump of get_charset(); it doesn't want to put € in my database :((

Comment: @Tessmore: I updated my solution, try it without the `call_user_func_array`.

Comment: Your first solution `$connection->set_charset('utf8');` actually did the trick, but I had a small error somewhere I overlooked while trying to implement this, so it took some time to see :)